# Hibernate Filter an associated entity in SpringBoot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this structs of tables

```
tb_country
 id | name
------------------------------- 
  1 | EUA
  2 | FRANCE
  3 | JAPAN

tb_cities
 id | name                  | country_id | save
-------------------------------------------------
  1 | CHICAGO               |     1      | true 
  2 | NY                    |     1      | true
  3 | SEATLE                |     1      | false
  4 | PARIS                 |     2      | true
  5 | NICE                  |     2      | true  
  6 | TOKIO                 |     3      | true  
  7 | NAGOIA                |     3      | false
```

So I need to return the country and the cities with `save = false`, in sql I create:

```
"SELECT * FROM tb_country c1 JOIN tb_cities c2 ON c2.country_id = c1.id WHERE c2.save = false;
```

the will return only

```
EUA -> SEATLE
JAPAN -> NAGOIA.
```

SO if I put that select in a HQL

```
SELECT t FROM TbCountry c JOIN c.cities c2 WHERE c2.save = false;
```

he will return the country EUA and JAPAN but he will return all cities from that country

If I put in my entity `@Where(clause = "save = false ")`  will return only SEATLE and NAGOIA but if I need to change that clause, how can I make this dynamic?

tks

Comment: Are tb_country.id and tb_cities.country_id joined with some mapping type in Entity? And can you post your Entity structure too?

Comment: Without knowing the entity objects and how exactly they're mapped, I can't say for sure, but this question has a thorough answer explaining what I believe is the same kind of issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711143/why-does-jpa-join-return-too-many-results